# ImportError HDFStore requires PyTables No module named tables

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.HDFStore('xxxxx.h5')
```

throws this error:

`"ImportError: HDFStore requires PyTables, "No module named tables" problem importing"`

I tried to install PyTables, which Requires Cython.
I have Cython 0.21 installed, but it is throwing an error stating that Cython should be greater than 0.13

Here is the log that I am getting:

```
".. ERROR:: You need Cython 0.13 or greater to compile PyTables!

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/tables
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/nikhilsahai/Library/Logs/pip.log
Nikhils-MacBook-Pro:~ nikhilsahai$ sudo pip install cython
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cython in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.21-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg
Cleaning up..."
```

Please guide me how to do solve this issue.

Comment: I assume you have some paths crossed and setup.py is findinging one version of cython and pip is finding a different one.

Comment: yeh, you need a much greater version of cython, 0.21 is the current

Comment: It's a bug in the released version of pytables: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/388. It's fixed in the dev version. Which you can install with `pip install git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables`

Answer (score 53):

Simply updating `pytables` with:

```
pip install --upgrade tables
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

I also had the same error when using **HDFStore**. And I tried all the steps specified above and spent many hours to find a solution, but non of them were successful.

Then I downloaded and installed [MiniConda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). And then I used the below command to install pytables.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pytables
```

Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

On Ubuntu, I solved this problem using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tables
```

Note that I am using Python 3

Comment: or `pkg install py27-tables-3.2.2_1`

Comment: or just `pip install tables` for python 3

Comment: @shadi I use Linux and prefer to stick to the package manager.

Comment: You're kind of restricting your options unnecessarily. With pip you can choose different versions. Pip is also a package manager btw.

Comment: @shadi Read this article: http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_on_debian.html. It has a balanced view explaining the pros and cons of apt-get vs pip. I prefer using apt-get for stability reasons, others prefer pip to get other benefits such as better control on the package they want. It also seems preferable to use virtualenv in conjunction with pip.

Comment: Valid points. I use [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew) as a wrapper for virtualenv

Comment: Using a dockerfile (with the base image of python3-slim), adding ```ENV HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial```, and installing both ```apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev``` and ```pip install tables``` seemed to work. Other solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use pip on any os :

python -m pip install tables

You can check the official documentation on more ways to install it 
http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html

Comment: I can confirm: this solves the problem on MacOS and both python2 and python3 (`python2 -m pip install tables` and `python3 -m pip install tables`)

Answer (score 2):

As TomAugspurger mentioned... It seems there is a bug with the latest version of pytables. You can install the current development version by executing the following command:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables
```

If it solved the problem, the question should be closed :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to install pytables:

`conda install pytables`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows,maybe that is a good choices,using this Command:

pip installed tables-3.2.2-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl

---the document you can download from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy