# Missing optional dependency 'tables'. In pandas to_hdf

Tags: python, pandas, pip, hdf5, pytables

- following code is giving me error.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3]})
df.to_hdf('temp.h5', key='df', mode='w')
```

- This is giving me error.

  > Missing optional dependency 'tables'.  Use pip or conda to install tables.
- I already tried 
  [ImportError HDFStore requires PyTables No module named tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980018/importerror-hdfstore-requires-pytables-no-module-named-tables). Still the same error.
- I am getting the same error when reading hdf file. And `tables` are already installed for my python.

Some version info.

> - python 3.7.4
> - pandas 0.25.2
> - windows10

PS: You can reproduce this in `repl` https://repl.it/.

**Update**:

- I tried runnig following.

```
import tables
```

and got this error:

> ImportError: Could not load any of ['hdf5.dll', 'hdf5dll.dll'], please ensure that it can be found in the system path.

- It looks like pandas is not giving accurate message for this. Its just saying missing dependency when its actually present.
- If anyone knows how to resolve this. That will help.

Comment: What is your operating system, python executable location, and what IDE are you using (PyCharm, VSCode, etc?)  Also, what version of Pandas and Python are you using?

Comment: On repl.it your code runs fine once you add tables==3.6.0 as a package in the repl.

Comment: @DavideFiocco it looks like right now its working on relt.it. I am not on my home work station right now. Once i will get back to home i will check and update the question.

Comment: @James version info are mentioned in question. I am using jupyter notebook to run the code.

Comment: on my Linux machine the package seems to be called `pytables`. Can you check if installing `pytables` resolves your issue? Your code snippet works fine with `pytables` installed.

Comment: What package manager do you use? Can you try reinstalling the desired package with pip or conda and see if the import is successful?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I am using pip to install this. Also its still failing after reinstallation of package.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- The issue was with `tables`.
- When i was installing `tables` using pip into local user directory using following command it's not working.

```
pip install --user tables
```

- Running `import tables` will result in this error.

  > ImportError: Could not load any of ['hdf5.dll', 'hdf5dll.dll'], please ensure that it can be found in the system path
- The solution that worked for me is to uninstall tables. And install it into python's directory. (or where your python is installed). `without --user option`. You may require admin/root access for this depending upon location of your python.
- For me my python path was `C:\Program Files\Python37-64\python.exe` and installing under `c:\program files\python37-64\lib\site-packages\` worked for me.
- Hope this helps. I don't know why installing in user directory is not working for tables. If anyone can find the reason for that please post here.

Answer (score 34):

For conda users:

```
conda install pytables
```

Comment: Perfect. Installs both tables and numexpr into site-packages.

Comment: For me, the same 'missing tables' error was raised from `miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py` in `__init__` when executing `tables = import_optional_dependency("tables")` which seems to indicate `pytables` module was already installed. Still your solution solved the problem. Can't understand.

Comment: I had the same issue as @mins but `conda `wouldn't resolve.  `pip install tables` did the trick

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work by using

```
conda install snappy
```

Comment: I don't know the reason, but it works for me.Thanks

Comment: Do you know why does this solution work (at least for some users)? It worked for me as well.. (`conda install pytables` didn't help me)

Answer (score 3):

using tables 3.6.1 worked for me to resolve the dependency

```
pip install tables==3.6.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions did not work for me. Perhaps because I built the individual environment using the conda-forge channel, I had success with this:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pytables
```

Answer (score 2):

I used following command successfully resolved this problem:

```
pip install --upgrade tables
```

hope that work for you !

Answer (score 0):

This problem has appeared for me when refreshing an existing conda virtal env using `pip install -U -r requirements.txt`. I resolved the issue as follows:

1. `conda env remove -n <env> # remove your virtual env.`
2. `conda create -n <env> python==3.8 # create your virtual env again.`
3. `pip install -U -r requirements.txt`

It's quite tedius to maintain a mix of conda and pip packages, so I just use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Using MacOS Ventura on Apple M2 processor the above was not working for me. What finally was working for me:

```
env HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5 python3 -m pip install tables
```

Where `/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5` is the `hdf5` installation location